# Primefaces Datatable cannot display values of List<interfaces>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have 2 beans (BeanA,BeanB) that implement the same interface (IBean).

what I am trying to do is display Into the `<p:datatable>` a list of IBean (`List<IBean>`).

here is the sample xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable 
id="table" 

value="#{modelBeanMB.myIBeanList}" 
var="row"
scrollable="true"
emptyMessage="#{msg.emptyDataTable}"
scrollHeight="350"
>
.....
</p:dataTable>
```

And my MB is Like:

```
 protected List<IBean> myIBeanList;

 public List<IBean> getMyIBeanList() {
    return myIbeanList;
 }
  public void setMyIBeanList(List<IBean>   myIbeanList) {
    this.myIbeanList= myIbeanList;
 }
```

the strange thig is that the table display all the rows of the list but not the single element value. like this:

[image]

as you can see the table has everithing (columns and rows)  but not data even if BeanA and BeanB are filled.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i feel so ashamed.

the problem is this:
      var="row"
I did not realize that i was using a different name into `<p:columns>` tags and not primefaces neither jsf told me that i was using different names.

**The moral of the story is:** always check twice that you are using the same property name here

```
<p:dataTable 
id="table"
value="#{modelBeanMB.myIBeanList}" 
***var="row"***
scrollable="true"
emptyMessage="#{msg.emptyDataTable}"
scrollHeight="350"
>
```

and here

```
   <p:column header="">
      **#{row.attribute}**
    </p:column>
```

because Jsf and primefaces will not tell you what you are doing wrong :)

Best regards

Comment: That is why you should ** always** post an mcve... Not leave relevant things out!!! (but do not leave irrelevant things in either)

Comment: it says that i have to wait 19 hours

Answer (score -1):

it's normal.Because your value ***{modelBeanMB.myIBeanList}*** and it is empty.You should fill in method.

Comment: i did not wrote the part in wich i fill the list because it is useless and in case of empty list primefaces does not draw any line. Plus, in case of empty list, there is the attribute "emptyMessage" that writes the specified message.

Comment: ok understand. if you write all method maybe I can help u.Getter and setter methods ok?